# How to show list of data in auto complete text box for minimum 2 character using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Here Is My Angular controller where I am getting the list of value

`$scope.Trucks=result.data.Trucks;`

**Below is the html**

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-5">Truck Number </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></div>
        <input style="max-width: 600px !important;" class="form-control required" ng-model="Trucknumber" type="text" placeholder="Truck Number" id="trucknumber"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use any autocomplete plugin?

Comment: I am unable to bind the list of data when I type 2 character

Comment: `result.data.Trucks` what does this contain. You question is not clear need to add more details to it. Like if you are using any plugin

Comment: No I am not using any directive.result.data.trucks having list of truck number.can u share any link of angular autocomplete text box when u type minimum 2 character.

Answer (score 0):

Do google with keyword: "angucomplete"
And create an element like this:

```
<angucomplete id="ex1"
              placeholder="Search trucks"
              pause="100"
              selectedobject="Trucknumber"
              localdata="Trucks"
              searchfields="yourfieldname"
              titlefield="yourfieldname"
              minlength="2"
              inputclass="form-control form-control-small"/>
```

Comment: This will be my html.Bt what will be controller where we can bind data

Answer (score 0):

Here,I made working demo for autocomplete search as you want please check below link:
[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/hirojaisinghani/pen/NRQjqr)

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

<title>Truck Number</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>

<body>

    <div class="form-group col-md-5" ng-app="autoSearch"
        ng-controller="autoSearch">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-5">Truck Number </label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
            <input style="max-width: 600px !important;"
                class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="Truck Number"
                id="searchLocation" auto-complete ui-items="number"
                ng-model="selected" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Angular JS:

```
var app = angular.module('autoSearch', []);

app.controller('autoSearch', function($scope) {
  $scope.number = ['2122','2322','4343','32323','43434'];
}).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source:  scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            minLength:2,
            select: function(e, ui) {               
                $timeout(function() {                   
                    scope.selected = ui.item.value;

                }, 100);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Please check that code and let me know if you have any query in that.
I hope that will work for you
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks..It is working for typing,bt when put in html  minlength="2"  it works as before .

Comment: You need to define minLength in directive. I changed in code and working example minlength to 2.
Please check and let me know if you still face the issue.
Thanks